# React: why does value inside JSON.stringify render but doesn't without?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I feel like I am making a very rookie mistake here, but can't quite figure this out.

So I have a rather simple component like this:

```
const Comp = props => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({})

    const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
        const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/data/${props.match.params.id}`, AuthHeaders)
        console.log(res.data)
        setData(res.data)
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
    }, [fetchData])

    return (
        <div>{data.name}</div>
    )
}
```

Now, here when I try to display `data.name` inside my return statement, it shows a `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` error and the `console.log(res.data)` inside the `fetchData` function returns an empty object. However, if I replace the return statement with this code below, it shows the data object as a string and the `console.log` shows the object.

```
return (
    <div>
        {JSON.stringify(data)}
    </div>
    )
```

Like I said, I am fairly certain I am making a very stupid mistake, but would really appreciate if someone points me to the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify things, what type of file are you fetching? Single Object or array of objects?

Comment: It's a single object.

Comment: `<div>{data && data.name}</div>` - explained - if data is not undefined then display the name

Comment: Try my suggestion and give feedback